# Проблема с Production-версией приложения

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

**Всем доброго времени суток!**
Моя проблема заключается в том, что в `production`-версии `RoR` приложения имеются кое-какие неполадки с отображением. Вот что там - **http://foto-kladov.ru/**.

Впечатление, будто бы какие-то ресурсы/ассеты не были найдены. Насколько знаю, `production` версия отличается от запуска той же `development` или `test` версии. Нужно, к примеру, компилировать ресурсы. Так вот, собственно, очень хотелось бы узнать, в чем суть моей проблемы, уважаемые рубисты? Буду очень благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: > We're sorry, but something went wrong.

> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

без логов будет несколько проблематично

Comment: @0xFFh, я думаю, что у вас там есть авторизация администратора, но логи все равно скидывайте (лучше на какой-нибудь pastebin, чтобы экран всем не рвать).

Comment: @Fike, пожалуйста, можно чуть-чуть поподробнее на эту тему? Спасибо вам.

Comment: конец application.log (и других тоже, я не рубист, я не помню) из {appdir}/log скопируйте, пожалуйста, на pastebin.com и скиньте сюда ссылки.

Comment: Да вот проблема в том, что как раз файл логов из продакшн-версии отсутствует вовсе в папке слогами - там только dev и test..

Comment: @0xFFh, а в общем application.log что? Есть ли в вашей конфигурации продакшен?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rails App Not Serving Assets in Production Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904949/rails-app-not-serving-assets-in-production-environment)

опять же: я не рубист, поэтому будьте готовы откатить изменения, но:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

должно просто перенести статику (это не откатывается, но и не должно навредить)

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

в production.rb должно заставить рельсы автоматом переносить статику

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо :) Все-таки именно этот способ компиляции ресурсов мне помог!

Answer (score 0):

если вышеуказанный способ не сработал, можно попробовать в файле **config/environments/production.rb** вручную указать ассеты

```
    config.assets.precompile += %w(example.css.scss)
```